# Swapping axes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have been trying to pull some information from a MSSQL database and deposit it into a chart via ASP.NET v4 which has been easy.  The issue I am really struggling with are the X and Y axes.  For some reason, it will only allow me to have certain data on a particular axis which just happens to be the opposite (Axis) to what I want.  Could someone please point me in the right direction so that I can either choose what table data (Pulling name from Table 1 and the data from table 2) goes to which axis or if there is a way to force a swap via code?  Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

If it helps, this is my ASP.NET code.

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
Width="900px" Height="500px" style="margin-top: 5px" Palette="EarthTones">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="ActualWOB" 
            YValueMembers="Rig_ID" Legend="Legend" ChartType="Bar" YValuesPerPoint="4">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="Legend" Title="Legend">
        </asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```

I want the ID/Name to be on the X Axis and the ActualWOB data on the Y Axis but just can't seem to figure it out.  Could it be something to do with my SQL Query?  There are 2 Tables as mentioned earlier.  One has ID, name, Manager, status and the other table has all the actual recorded data with the ID tying the 2 tables together.  Because there are multiple names, I want to have the Names going up the chart with all the data fields on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not 100% sure how, but I resolved this.  I think it was just a dodgy SQL Query.